# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError while executing maven commands

Tags: maven

I'm not an expert in maven. I have installed maven in fedora 22. 
The installation details are:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (NON-CANONICAL_2015-04-01T06:42:27_mockbuild; 2015-04-01T02:42:27-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.91-2.b14.fc22.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.0.4-301.fc22.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

The project which I'm trying to build using maven is already configured in maven and it is working in other environment. This is a new setup where I'm trying to build the project but I'm unable to understand the exception:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
---------------------------------------------------
constituent[0]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/cdi-apicdi-api.jar
constituent[1]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jsr-305.jar
constituent[2]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model.jar
constituent[3]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aether_aether-api.jar
constituent[4]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus_plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar
constituent[5]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-aether-provider.jar
constituent[6]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-codec.jar
constituent[7]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/httpcomponents_httpcore.jar
constituent[8]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus_utils.jar
constituent[9]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-wagon_http-shared.jar
constituent[10]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus_containers-component-annotations.jar
constituent[11]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aether_aether-spi.jar
constituent[12]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/httpcomponents_httpclient.jar
constituent[13]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-wagon_file.jar
constituent[14]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-core.jar
constituent[15]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-repository-metadata.jar
constituent[16]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/geronimo-annotation.jar
constituent[17]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-embedder.jar
constituent[18]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aopalliance.jar
constituent[19]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aether_aether-util.jar
constituent[20]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.inject.jar
constituent[21]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-wagon_http-shaded.jar
constituent[22]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/guava.jar
constituent[23]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-plugin-api.jar
constituent[24]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aether_aether-impl.jar
constituent[25]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aether_aether-connector-basic.jar
constituent[26]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings-builder.jar
constituent[27]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.jar
constituent[28]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-wagon_provider-api.jar
constituent[29]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j_api.jar
constituent[30]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-cli.jar
constituent[31]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-compat.jar
constituent[32]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/jsoup_jsoup.jar
constituent[33]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-io.jar
constituent[34]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus_plexus-cipher.jar
constituent[35]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/google-guice-no_aop.jar
constituent[36]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-settings.jar
constituent[37]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-model-builder.jar
constituent[38]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/maven-artifact.jar
constituent[39]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/aether_aether-transport-wagon.jar
constituent[40]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/plexus_interpolation.jar
constituent[41]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/slf4j_simple.jar
constituent[42]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/objectweb-asm_asm.jar
constituent[43]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/atinject.jar
constituent[44]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-lang.jar
constituent[45]: file:/usr/share/maven/lib/commons-logging.jar
constituent[46]: file:/usr/share/maven/conf/logging/
---------------------------------------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC.initialize(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC.access$000(SunEC.java:49)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:61)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC$1.run(SunEC.java:58)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.SunEC.<clinit>(SunEC.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:221)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$2.run(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(ProviderConfig.java:206)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(ProviderConfig.java:187)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getProvider(ProviderList.java:233)
    at sun.security.jca.ProviderList.getService(ProviderList.java:331)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:157)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getDefault(SSLContext.java:96)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(SSLSocketFactory.java:122)
    at javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultSSLSocketFactory(HttpsURLConnection.java:332)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.createConnManager(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:344)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.AbstractHttpClientWagon.<clinit>(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:269)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.access$000(ConstructorInjector.java:32)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector$1.call(ConstructorInjector.java:92)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:133)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:269)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1066)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1044)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1009)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1059)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1005)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.transport.wagon.PlexusWagonProvider.lookup(PlexusWagonProvider.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.lookupWagon(WagonTransporter.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.<init>(WagonTransporter.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporterFactory.newInstance(WagonTransporterFactory.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultTransporterProvider.newTransporter(DefaultTransporterProvider.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.<init>(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.newInstance(BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.newRepositoryConnector(DefaultRepositoryConnectorProvider.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:439)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:241)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:337)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.resolveExtensionArtifacts(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.createProjectRealm(DefaultProjectBuildingHelper.java:240)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultModelBuildingListener.buildExtensionsAssembled(DefaultModelBuildingListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.ModelBuildingEventCatapult$1.fire(ModelBuildingEventCatapult.java:43)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.fireEvent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:1175)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:415)
    at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:398)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:614)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:406)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.collectProjects(DefaultMaven.java:673)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultMaven.java:663)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:253)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Any pointers to what may be causing the issue would help me immensely.

Comment: That doesn't look good. I would reinstall Maven completely...

Comment: I unpacked maven 3,3,9 and installed some more additional plugins. but still the same error.

Comment: You downloaded Maven 3.3.9 from https://maven.apache.org/ and unpacked it...and just to try to build your project? What do you mean by ` some more additional plugins`?

Comment: I added some packages like:maven-shared-io-1.1-12
maven-wagon-ssh-common-2.9-4.
maven-surefire-provider-testng-2.18.1-2.
maven-repository-builder-1.0-2.
maven-enforcer-api-1.4-2.

Comment: Where have you added those files? In the lib folder of the Maven installation ?

Comment: I installed those files using yum install <package_name>

Answer (score 3):

I have meet the same problem. 
It seems that new jre version with old version of nss-softokn cause this problem.
my mvn -v like this

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-11T00:41:47+08:00)
Maven home: /usr/lib/apache-maven
Java version: 1.7.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.111-2.6.7.2.el7_2.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-123.9.3.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

use command `rpm -q nss-softokn` to check the nss's version. mine like this

```
nss-softokn-3.16.2.3-13.el7_1.x86_64
```

if u have the same problem, try command `yum upgrade nss` to update nss lib. nss is upgraded to 3.21.0.

ref:

https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=11245

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1332456

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the maven installation folder `lib` if it contains the following files:

```
aether-api-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
aether-api.license
aether-connector-basic-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
aether-connector-basic.license
aether-impl-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
aether-impl.license
aether-spi-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
aether-spi.license
aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
aether-transport-wagon.license
aether-util-1.0.0.v20140518.jar
aether-util.license
aopalliance-1.0.jar
cdi-api-1.0.jar
cdi-api.license
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-io-2.2.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
guava-18.0.jar
javax.inject-1.jar
jsoup-1.7.2.jar
jsoup.license
jsr250-api-1.0.jar
jsr250-api.license
maven-aether-provider-3.2.5.jar
maven-aether-provider.license
maven-artifact-3.2.5.jar
maven-artifact.license
maven-compat-3.2.5.jar
maven-compat.license
maven-core-3.2.5.jar
maven-core.license
maven-embedder-3.2.5.jar
maven-embedder.license
maven-model-3.2.5.jar
maven-model-builder-3.2.5.jar
maven-model-builder.license
maven-model.license
maven-plugin-api-3.2.5.jar
maven-plugin-api.license
maven-repository-metadata-3.2.5.jar
maven-repository-metadata.license
maven-settings-3.2.5.jar
maven-settings-builder-3.2.5.jar
maven-settings-builder.license
maven-settings.license
org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.3.0.M1.jar
org.eclipse.sisu.inject.license
org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.3.0.M1.jar
org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.license
plexus-cipher-1.7.jar
plexus-cipher.license
plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
plexus-interpolation-1.21.jar
plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.3.jar
plexus-sec-dispatcher.license
plexus-utils-3.0.20.jar
sisu-guice-3.2.3-no_aop.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-api.license
slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar
slf4j-simple.license
wagon-file-2.8.jar
wagon-file.license
wagon-http-2.8-shaded.jar
wagon-http-shared-2.8.jar
wagon-http-shared.license
wagon-http.license
wagon-provider-api-2.8.jar
wagon-provider-api.license
```

The number of files should be the same what might differ is that the files are used without the version number (which is not good, but for Java it does not matter)...There must be 70 files (maybe the license files are omitted...

The problem is that you are using a package which is not packaged by Apache Project....

Comment: These are the files in /usr/share/mvn/lib:

Answer (score 0):

there are the files:

```
These are the files in /usr/share/mvn/lib:  lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   29 Apr  1  2015 slf4j_api.jar -> /usr/share/java/slf4j/api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   32 Apr  1  2015 plexus_utils.jar -> /usr/share/java/plexus/utils.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   48 Apr  1  2015 plexus_plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar -> /usr/share/java/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   40 Apr  1  2015 plexus_plexus-cipher.jar -> /usr/share/java/plexus/plexus-cipher.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   40 Apr  1  2015 plexus_interpolation.jar -> /usr/share/java/plexus/interpolation.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   59 Apr  1  2015 plexus_containers-component-annotations.jar -> /usr/share/java/plexus/containers-component-annotations.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   43 Apr  1  2015 org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.jar -> /usr/share/java/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   43 Apr  1  2015 org.eclipse.sisu.inject.jar -> /usr/share/java/org.eclipse.sisu.inject.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   35 Apr  1  2015 maven-settings.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-settings.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   43 Apr  1  2015 maven-settings-builder.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-settings-builder.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   46 Apr  1  2015 maven-repository-metadata.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-repository-metadata.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   37 Apr  1  2015 maven-plugin-api.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-plugin-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   32 Apr  1  2015 maven-model.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-model.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   40 Apr  1  2015 maven-model-builder.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-model-builder.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   35 Apr  1  2015 maven-embedder.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-embedder.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   31 Apr  1  2015 maven-core.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-core.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   33 Apr  1  2015 maven-compat.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-compat.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   35 Apr  1  2015 maven-artifact.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-artifact.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   42 Apr  1  2015 maven-aether-provider.jar -> ../../java/maven/maven-aether-provider.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   27 Apr  1  2015 jsr-305.jar -> /usr/share/java/jsr-305.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   31 Apr  1  2015 jsoup_jsoup.jar -> /usr/share/java/jsoup/jsoup.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   25 Apr  1  2015 guava.jar -> /usr/share/java/guava.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   39 Apr  1  2015 google-guice-no_aop.jar -> /usr/share/java/google-guice-no_aop.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   39 Apr  1  2015 geronimo-annotation.jar -> /usr/share/java/geronimo-annotation.jar
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Apr  1  2015 ext
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   32 Apr  1  2015 commons-lang.jar -> /usr/share/java/commons-lang.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   30 Apr  1  2015 commons-io.jar -> /usr/share/java/commons-io.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   31 Apr  1  2015 commons-cli.jar -> /usr/share/java/commons-cli.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   35 Apr  1  2015 cdi-apicdi-api.jar -> /usr/share/java/cdi-api/cdi-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   28 Apr  1  2015 atinject.jar -> /usr/share/java/atinject.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   31 Apr  1  2015 aopalliance.jar -> /usr/share/java/aopalliance.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   38 Apr  1  2015 aether_aether-util.jar -> /usr/share/java/aether/aether-util.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   49 Apr  1  2015 aether_aether-transport-wagon.jar -> /usr/share/java/aether/aether-transport-wagon.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   37 Apr  1  2015 aether_aether-spi.jar -> /usr/share/java/aether/aether-spi.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   38 Apr  1  2015 aether_aether-impl.jar -> /usr/share/java/aether/aether-impl.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   49 Apr  1  2015 aether_aether-connector-basic.jar -> /usr/share/java/aether/aether-connector-basic.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   37 Apr  1  2015 aether_aether-api.jar -> /usr/share/java/aether/aether-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   32 Apr  1  2015 slf4j_simple.jar -> /usr/share/java/slf4j/simple.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   37 Apr  1  2015 objectweb-asm_asm.jar -> /usr/share/java/objectweb-asm/asm.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   44 Apr  1  2015 maven-wagon_provider-api.jar -> /usr/share/java/maven-wagon/provider-api.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   43 Apr  1  2015 maven-wagon_http-shared.jar -> /usr/share/java/maven-wagon/http-shared.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   36 Apr  1  2015 maven-wagon_http-shaded.jar -> /usr/share/java/maven-wagon/http.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   36 Apr  1  2015 maven-wagon_file.jar -> /usr/share/java/maven-wagon/file.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   43 Apr  1  2015 httpcomponents_httpcore.jar -> /usr/share/java/httpcomponents/httpcore.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   45 Apr  1  2015 httpcomponents_httpclient.jar -> /usr/share/java/httpcomponents/httpclient.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   35 Apr  1  2015 commons-logging.jar -> /usr/share/java/commons-logging.jar
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   33 Apr  1  2015 commons-codec.jar -> /usr/share/java/commons-codec.jar
```